# react-dom.production.min.js:275 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130 only production build

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, production

In developer mode, the code runs fine but the production build breaks with this error message.
I put back the earlier version which I could build a running version from. But now if I build it again, I get this runtime error.
I deleted the package-lock.json, node-modules and reinstall it, but it didn't help.

Comment: I had to downgrade my node

Comment: what version did you downgrade to?